# How to convert a JSONObject to a String Array or ArrayList<String> in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm going to get the values of a JSONObject and put it in a String Array or ArrayList. the Problem is that I have a JSONObject not a JSONArray, and I can't change the Webservice.
This is my JSONObject:

{"THR":"تهران",
"MHD":"مشهد",
"KIH":"کیش",
"IFN":"اصفهان",
"SYZ":"شیراز",
"TBZ":"تبریز",
"ABD":"آبادان"}

And this is my code:

```
    ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

when I debug my code, it goes to CATCH!!!
It doesn't go to TRY, anyway!

I want something like this:

```
String[] strArray = {"تهران","مشهد","کیش","اصفهان","شیراز","تبریز","آبادان"};
```

How can I get it?

Comment: object can't cast to array

Comment: can you try this ?
JSONArray array = new JSONArray("["+response+"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added changes to your code

```
ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayList<String> answersStringArray= new ArrayList<String>(); // define string array

progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                JJSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); //cast responce to jsonObject
                Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys(); // get the keys of the jsonObject
                while( keys.hasNext() ) {//iterrate over them
                    String key = (String)keys.next();
                    answersStringArray.add(jsonObject.optString(key));}// add the string to our array of stings


          } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Catch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//building your jsonObject(took only the 1st four ;P )
        JSONObject objJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        objJsonObject.put("THR", "تهران");
        objJsonObject.put("MHD", "مشهد");
        objJsonObject.put("KIH", "کیش");
        objJsonObject.put("IFN", "اصفهان");
        String [] strArray= new String[objJsonObject.length()];
        int i = 0;
//adding your required data into a array
        for (String key: objJsonObject.keySet()) {
            strArray[i] = objJsonObject.getString(key);
            i++;
        }
//printing your data
        for (int j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(strArray[j]);
        }
}
```

hope this helps....

Comment: Oh no, the length of my JSONObject is too long, this is just a part of my JSONObject. I did that to simplify the question.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali i don't see how the length of your jsonObject matters here? can you make yourself more clear? as far as your question goes the above code gives you what you need...